# HttpResponseProxy HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authorization

I have a GET request that works well on Postman, but doesn't on Eclipse. Everytime I get this response:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized [Cache-Control: no-cache, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Expires: -1, Server: , WWW-Authenticate: Raven, Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 09:47:13 GMT, Content-Length: 32, X-Cache: MISS from proxy, X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy:3191, X-Cache: MISS from site.domain.com, X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from site.domain.com:8668, Via: 1.0 proxy:3191 (squid/2.6.STABLE21), 1.0 site.domain.com (squid/3.1.10), Connection: keep-alive]}
```

This is how I do my call:

```
    //String request; String key;

    String signature = generateSignature(request, "HmacSHA256");

    Resource resource = restClient.newBuilder()
            .type(TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
            .constructCollectionType(List.class, MyObject.class))
            .timeout(30000)
            .header("Authorization", "Raven " + signature)
            .header("X-Raven-ApiKey", key)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .param("SinceDate", sinceDate)
            .param("Timestamp", String.valueOf(timestamp))
            .build();
    return resource.get();
```

What can be the possible reasons of getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the signature is not well encoded. 401 means that the authorization process has failed, probably because the Raven signature is not valid (or maybe due to the Raven API key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cdelmas you were rignt. I used Base64 to encode my signature, and it was adding "\r\n" characters in the end. I removed them and it works.